# How to convert sas binary datetime to dd/mm/yyyy in webout file

Tags: sql, file, datetime, binary, sas

I've a table named cust_field_value_l in sas server under Sasoprsk library having a column name value_dt who store date data.

When I get data from this table it comes in binary data as `1.827E9` or `1.826E9` and gives ***** when i print it in my webout file.

```
proc sql noprint;
 create table date(date datetime);
quit;

proc sql noprint;
 insert into date(date)
 select value_dt
 from Sasoprsk.cust_field_value_l;
quit;
```

Now my date table has data as `1.826E9` etc.

```
data _null_;
 put "<html><body>";
run;

data _null_;
  put numberOfObservations=;
 set work.date nobs=numberOfObservations;
 file _webout; 
 put date;
run;

data _null_;
 put "</body></html>";
run;
```

I'm receiving ***** in my webout file

I've tried this too but it only giving me wrong date

```
proc sql noprint;
 insert into date(date)
 select (today()-datepart((value_dt  / 1000.0)+315601200)) 
 from Sasoprsk.cust_field_value_l;
quit;
```

this code giving me only `03NOV07` for all the date values.

I don't know how can i get correct date value from db and show them in webout file;

value_dt has all the values in 23NOV2017:00:00:00 formate.

```
value_dt
23NOV2017:00:00:00
15NOV2017:00:00:00
20NOV2017:00:00:00
```

without comparing with today()

```
date
1.827E9
1.826E9
1.827E9
```

and its giving me ***** for every row

with comparing with today()

```
date
03NOV07
03NOV07
03NOV07
```

and printing 03NOV07 for every date data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SAS only has two data types. Fixed length character strings and floating point numbers.  DATE values are stored as the number of days since `'01JAN1960'd` and DATETIME values are stored as the number of seconds since `'01JAN1960:00:00'dt`. The numbers you are displaying are consistent with a datetime value.  The `TODAY()` function (also know as the `DATE()` function) will return a DATE value.  If you want a DATETIME value use the `DATETIME()` function instead.

If you want users to supply date values (like '03NOV2007'd) to filter your datetime variable then you will need to convert one or the other before comparing them. Say you have a datetime variable name TIMESTAMP and you want to find events that occured today you could use something like

```
where today() = datepart(timestamp)
```

If you are creating a new data set by reading values from an existing dataset then just use a DATA step. No need to pre-creating the dataset and then "inserting" the observations into it.  Or to bother with using PROC SQL.  Just create the dataset you want.

```
data date ;
  set Sasoprsk.cust_field_value_l ;
  keep value_dt ;
  rename value_dt=date ;
  format value_dt datetime20. ;
run;
```

But if the whole purpose is just to print the values to the `_WEBOUT` fileref then there is no need to make a copy of the data first. Just print directly from the source data.

```
data _null_;
  put numberOfObservations=;
  set Sasoprsk.cust_field_value_l nobs=numberOfObservations;
  file _webout; 
  put value_dt datetime20.;
run;
```

If you only want to print the date part of the datetime value then you can use the `DTDATE9.` format instead.

Comment: I can't direct display my date values because I've to create a data set for my report. it may contain filters so I've to create a data-set using those filters then i can print that table to my webout file.

Comment: I'm coping values from cust_field_value_dt where cust_field_nm equals to my desired field like x_app_dte_date and placing them into date table but when i display it in my webout it only showing me 03NOV07 for all date values or **

Comment: If your values are datetime (number of SECONDS) and you try to display using DATE format then you will get **** because the number is waaaaaaaay to big to be a valid date (number of DAYS).  You can use the DATEPART() function to convert a datetime value to a date value.  But you still need to use a format to get it appear in a human readable form.  Without a date type format it will just be a large number.

Comment: proc sql noprint;
 insert into date(date)
 select (today()-datepart((value_dt  / 1000.0)+315601200)) 
 from Sasoprsk.cust_field_value_l;
quit;

Comment: I tried this but its giving me 03NOV07 for every date. i created a record with having date of today and this code is still showing 03NOV07 for that too.

Comment: That date is day number 17,473. Find out why your variables value is always that value.

Comment: Thanks for help. I solved the issue using datepart(timestamps) only